# Multitriggers doesn't work with Entry in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have a `MAUI` `ContentPage` with the ViewModel. In this page, I have a `Picker` that saves the selected item in the property *WordType* (it can be *Noun* or *Verb*).

```xml
<Picker x:Name="pickerWordType"
    ItemsSource="{Binding WordTypes}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding WordType}"
    Style="{StaticResource pickerEditStyle}">
</Picker>
```

When the selected value is *Verb*, I want to display a `Label` and an `Entry`. For this reason, I use the `Triggers`. I wrote the following XAML:

```xml
<Label Text="Infinite" IsVisible="false">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Label">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding WordType}" Value="Verb" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
<Entry BindingContext="{Binding Tense1}" IsVisible="false">
    <Entry.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Entry">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding WordType}" Value="Verb" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

The `Triggers` is working for the `Label` but not for the `Entry` and the conditions are exactly the same.

Comment: What is `Tense1` and where is it defined? And why are you setting the `BindingContext` of the Entry? This shouldn't be necessary, the `BindingContext` is usually passed down to the control and only needs to be set directly in rare cases. Remove the `BindingContext` from the Entry and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `WordType` probably doesn't exist in the `BindingContext` that you're passing to the Entry. If exactly the same code works for the Label, then remove the `BindingContext` from the Entry:

```xml
<Entry IsVisible="false">
    <Entry.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger TargetType="Entry">
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding WordType}" Value="Verb" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed that I added `BindingContext` instead of `Text`. Thank you!